# How to strech divs inside other div

Tags: css, html

I want my 3 child divs to be stretched 100% vertically, and I want them to be next to each other horizontally. So If I resize my parent div, child divs will resize accordingly, but would always stay next to each other horizontally (each would take approximately 33% width)

So here is the CSS:

```
.appcontent {
    position: absolute;
    left: 80px;
    right: 50px;
    top: 30px;
    max-width: 1050px;
    min-height: 400px;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

.box {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 98%;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 2px solid black; 
}
```

And HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery demo</title>
  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="appcontent">
    <div class="box">
        <h3>App 1</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <h3>App 2</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <h3>App 3</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

just in case I also put it here http://jsfiddle.net/naWsh/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered this question before with a comprehensive explanation [Fluid design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14168051/mobile-webpage-layout-carousel-like/14308790#14308790)

Just in stead of 400% make it 100% and its children 33%

Comment: I just have one question, I used your example, and it works just fine, but if I try to put `margin: 5px;` it has no effect, is there any way to split cells in the table?

Comment: Well not to split cells, but the example uses containers. You can use those containers to create margins

Comment: Thank you @Chris Visser I, just figured it out, `border-spacing: 10px;` in `wrapper` will do the trick that I want. Sorry for bothering you.

Comment: Well, i'm here to help people. So glad I could help you out.